# Differentiable function such that $\left| f(x) \right| \leq C x^{-k}$ and $\left| f'(x) \right| \leq C' x^{-k}$ has limit at zero.

Tags: real-analysis

**The problem is:**

Let $f$ be differentiable real valued function, such that for $x>0$ we have

$$
\left|f(x) \right| \leq C x^{-k}
$$

for some positive constants $k$ and $C$, and the rate of growth is optimal, i.e there is no smaller $k$ that works.

If

$$
\left|f'(x) \right| \leq C' x^{-k}
$$

then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+} f(x)$ exists.

---

I don't really know what to do here, I assume we have to use the mean value theorem to show that if $x_n \to 0$ then $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence but I can't see how.

Answer (score 0):

I think $f(x) = ln(x)$ is a contadiction, maybe I didn't understand the question.

Comment: I think for $\log x$ there is no optimal positive $k$ since an arbitrary small positive $k$ would do.

Comment: Yes, I think at least $k = 1/2$ works for $f$ but not for the derivative and $k$ is supposed to be the smallest possible constant.